# Labelling or Skip logic in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert BTEQ to snwflake scripts and in which we have skip logic using labels.

It skips the particular query which we don't want to run and proceeds further. How to do the similar task in Snowflake ?

Example script:

Query #1 :

```
select sal from emp limit  1:

Activity =0 

label exit 

insert into abc from xyz

.exit
```

As shown above, if my first query does not return any records, I don't want to proceed further in the script or skip a particular next query and execute the further queries.

How to implement the similar operation in Snowflake?

Comment: Currently, you'd need to convert this logic to a javascript stored procedure.

Comment: You could use a bash script which uses  SnowSQL too I think. Usually BTEC scripts can be converted to bash without too much hassle